# Is the command line used when opening a file from the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, command-line, vb6

When I use Internet Explorer (or any other browser) and I try to download a file, I can get a little menu that asks if I would like to "open or save" the file. If I click "open," what command line is run and is there a way for me to see or capture that command line prompt in a VB6 application?

For example, Internet Explorer asks me if I want to open or save a .abc file. I click open. I want MyProject1.exe (written in VB6) to read the command line that is used to open that .abc file. (Assuming a file association already exists between MyProject1.exe and .abc extensions)

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems far more likely that IE calls ShellExecute than creating any "command line."

Comment: It might depend on the `content-type` HTTP header that comes with the downloaded file, as well as / rather than file associations and file extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in the command line arguments via the Command() function

Try the following test project:

```
'1 project with:
'  0 forms
'  1 module
'  Startup Object in Project properties should be set to Sub Main
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
  Dim intArg As Integer
  Dim strCmd As String
  Dim strArg() As String
  Dim strShow As String
  'read the command line
  strCmd = Command
  If Len(strCmd) > 0 Then
    'split the command line over its arguments
    strArg = Split(strCmd, " ")
    'show the commandline arguments
    strShow = CStr(UBound(strArg) + 1) & " command line arguments :"
    For intArg = 0 To UBound(strArg)
      strShow = strShow & vbCrLf & "Argument " & CStr(intArg) & " : " & strArg(intArg)
    Next intArg
    MsgBox strShow
  Else
    MsgBox "No command line arguments"
  End If
End Sub
```

Compile this project into an exe and call it with various command line arguments

When call the .exe without any command line arguments, then it will show a messagebox with the text "No command line arguments"

When you call the .exe with some command line arguments, then it will show a messagebox which tells you how many arguments there are, and what they are

Now choose this exe when you open a file from the webbrowser, and have a look at its arguments

Comment: to test how a downloaded program is run, you can download the exe you made here and execute it from the webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple a topic.

There is what the server says it is, then it's extension, then it's pattern matched to work out what it is. On local files it's extension then pattern matching.

There are various ways of opening a file. Command lines are most common but there are newer ways using COM. If both specified COM will be used.

If you just want to know what is **probably** going to open your file.

```
assoc .txt
```

then what ever it says

```
ftype txtfile
```

EG

```
C:\Users\User>assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile

C:\Users\User>ftype txtfile
txtfile=c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe "%1"
```

%1 is replaced with the file name in question.